# Grouping Sale Quantities and Sale Figures by Days of the week using sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

Database:  SQL Server 2008

I need to produce a sales report which groups sales figures into days of the week, e.g.;

```
Product          Mon  Tues  Wed Thurs Friday Sat Sunday   Total

Product 1        5    2     0   4     3      2   1        17
Product 2        2    1     4   3     1      1   1        13
```

I have two joined tables tbl_orders (primary table holding order no, order status etc.), tbl_orderitems (table holding item information, qty, price, product etc).

The date field is dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp

Structure of joined tables;

```
SELECT 
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders,
  dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_ref,
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_order_custid,
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_order_webid,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_status,
  dbo.tbl_orders.uid_order_addid,
  dbo.tbl_orders.mon_order_tax,
  dbo.tbl_orders.mon_order_grandtotal,
  dbo.tbl_orders.mon_order_discount,
  dbo.tbl_orders.bit_order_preorder,
  dbo.tbl_orders.int_order_deposit_percent,
  dbo.tbl_orders.mon_order_delivery,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_deltype,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_process,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_voucher_code,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_terms,
  dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_paydate,
  dbo.tbl_orders.int_order_taxrate,
  dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_googleid,
  dbo.tbl_orders.bit_order_archive,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orderitems,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_pcatid,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_psubcatid,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.int_orderitems_qty,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_stype,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pref,
  dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_prodid
FROM
  dbo.tbl_orders
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orderitems ON (dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders = dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid)
```

I am using the following statement to get overall sales figures, can i adapt this to group by days of the week? Not really sure where to start, i have done some reading on `datepart` but not quite sure how to implement it, or would i be better to wrap select statements?

```
SELECT 
        SUM(dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice) AS prodTotal,
        AVG(dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice) AS avgPrice,
        count(dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_prodid) AS prodQty,
        dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
        FROM dbo.tbl_orderitems
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders ON (dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid = dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders)
        WHERE dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_status = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.sale_status#">

        GROUP BY
        dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname 
        ORDER BY dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname ASC
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which column is your date field?

Comment: hi arion, i have updated question, what a numpty, leaving the date out!! dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `PIVOT`. Like this:

```
SELECT
    pvt.txt_orditems_pname AS Product,
    pvt.[Monday],
    pvt.[Tuesday],
    pvt.[Wednesday],
    pvt.[Thursday],
    pvt.[Friday],
    pvt.[Saturday],
    pvt.[Sunday],
    (
        pvt.[Monday]+pvt.[Tuesday]+pvt.[Wednesday]+pvt.[Thursday]+pvt.[Friday]+
        pvt.[Saturday]+pvt.[Sunday]
    ) AS Total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp) AS WeekDayName,
            dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice,
            dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
        FROM dbo.tbl_orderitems
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders 
            ON (dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid = dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders)
        WHERE 
            dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_status = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.sale_status#">
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(mon_orditems_pprice)
        FOR WeekDayName IN([Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],
                           [Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday],[Sunday])
    )
    AS pvt
```

Or if you do not want to use a `PIVOT`. You can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    t.txt_orditems_pname AS Product,
    t.[Monday],
    t.[Tuesday],
    t.[Wednesday],
    t.[Thursday],
    t.[Friday],
    t.[Saturday],
    t.[Sunday],
    (
        t.[Monday]+t.[Tuesday]+t.[Wednesday]+t.[Thursday]+t.[Friday]+
        t.[Saturday]+t.[Sunday]
    ) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=7 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Sunday],
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=1 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Saturday],
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=2 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Monday],
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=3 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Tuesday],
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=4 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Wednesday],
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=5 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Thursday],
        SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,dbo.tbl_orders.dte_order_stamp)=6 THEN dbo.tbl_orderitems.mon_orditems_pprice ELSE NULL END) AS [Friday],
        dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
    FROM dbo.tbl_orderitems
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders 
        ON (dbo.tbl_orderitems.uid_orditems_orderid = dbo.tbl_orders.uid_orders)
    WHERE 
        dbo.tbl_orders.txt_order_status = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.sale_status#">
    GROUP BY
        dbo.tbl_orderitems.txt_orditems_pname
) AS t
```

Comment: wicked works a treat!!! thank you. wheres the best place to learn more about this!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help:P. When you want to do columns to rows a PIVOT is almost in every cases the best pick. But it is easier to maybe understand the case sum way. Read on mdsn on the functions used you will have to choose what you like.